# click on javascript button in selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a web page that contains many records in a row.Each row have same button name,Since each button name in the records are same button name I cant use xpathid.Xpath id value is same to for al  buttons in each row.xpath value is //*[@id="btnChangeStatusThisOrder"] .If I am using this id for a row to get a click,it  wont work for that row since the same xpath id is using for many records in the web page,following are the html source code for 2 different rows in the page.Here I want to click on the javascript button of one record.'Go' is the button name in gui.

```
<a href="javascript: handleOrderStatusChange('247')" id="btnChangeStatusThisOrder" class="actionBtn">Go</a> ||||||<a href="javascript: handleOrderStatusChange('248')" id="btnChangeStatusThisOrder" class="actionBtn">Go</a>`
```

Comment: we need 2 rows screenshot as well as HTML code of 2 rows, to write a unique identifier.

Comment: Update the question with more of the outerHTML

Comment: @cruisepandey you can use row index in your xpath with id to find perticular element, for eg. `.//a[@id='btnChangeStatusThisOrder'][1]` where you can change index according to you row.

Comment: or more like :`(.//a[@id='btnChangeStatusThisOrder'])[1]` , where index number depends on how many items are there with this id and what is position of the button you are trying to click

Comment: @SaurabhGaur : yes,  we could do that. But what I feel, that based on some unique content we should write the xpath. like `//a[text()='SomeUniqueText']/following-sibling::button`, and obviously there should be unique content.

Comment: @cruisepandey if that is case, you need to provide more html content around target element so that we can try to find unique locator..:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur : yeah, exactly I asked OP to update the question.

Comment: @cruisepandey Oh sorry, I thought you had asked the question..:D

Comment: <a href="javascript: handleOrderStatusChange('247')" id="btnChangeStatusThisOrder" class="actionBtn">Go</a>  this is the html code for one row